# Storing data popularity in a Ruby on Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, popularity

I was reading [this Stack Overflow question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11602/what-formula-should-be-used-to-determine-hot-questions?s=b60d454e-da38-4866-9c7b-f0c5151346c4) and was wondering what is a common practice to store popularity values for data in a Ruby on Rails application?

My thinking is to have 2 models, a **regular** model and a **popular** one that has data from the **regular** model sorted by a ***popularity formula***. A cronjob would populate the latter model at some specific interval.

Any thoughts?

Comment: why can't you store popularity in a column in same model?

Answer (score 0):

It would depend on the specifics, but I think you can store the popularity information as a column in the model. For example, if you had Questions which you wanted to sort by popularity, you could run a migration `AddPopularityToQuestions popularity:float`.

You could then run a script at set intervals (e.g. with [Whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever)) to update the popularity value for each question. However, if there isn't that much activity, it might make more sense to update the popularity for a question whenever something happens that will change it.  For example, if popularity is mainly determined by votes, you could update a question's popularity whenever there are new votes.

Answer (score 0):

Use one rake task to update the popularity and run it with [heroku scheduler](https://addons.heroku.com/scheduler).

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine popularity to be statistical. For example, views over the last 7 days, etc. The measurement you might want to use might change, even allowing the user to select which formula to use.

In this case, you'd want a Statistics model that belongs_to the regular model, and you can join the tables to get the popularity measurement that you're interested in.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with a popularity_score field in the model and a scope that returns the popular items for example:

```
def popular(count = 10)
  order('popularity_score DESC').limit(count)
end
```

depending on the scoring algorithm, I may add additional model to hold the statistics

```
class model_stats
  attr_accessor :statistic, :value
  belongs_to :model
end
```

This could hold stats like views, up_votes or shares which would be periodically aggregated  using your preferred popularity algorithm and the result saved into popularity_score.  (managed as a rake task kicked off by cron or similar)

I would make sure that popularity_score was an indexed field!